# Access Error With Disconnected ADO Recordset

Tags: ms-access, ado

I'm testing a datasheet form that's bound to a disconnected ADO recordset. When I edit any part of any record I get the following error message after the update has occurred:

"The data was added to the database but the data won't be displayed in the
form because it doesn't satisfy the criteria in the underlying record source."

I'm using a client side cursor since this is the only way you can disconnect and persist the recordset. Also, I have code that re-establishes the connection while the update occurs and then disconnects it again afterwards.

I'm not using any triggers or stored procedures. I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express and Access 2007 (all updates installed) on Windows XP SP3. I'm using ActiveX Data Objects 2.8.

I found this article and installed the hotfix. I've rebooted my computer but the problem continues.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961451

Any ideas?

**Edit1:**
Code Example:

```
'rst is a form level variable (ADO Recordset Object)
With rst
    Set .ActiveConnection = gCon 'Global ADO Connection Object
    .Source = "SELECT i.*, c.lft FROM tblInventory AS i LEFT JOIN tblCat AS c ON i.catid = c.catid"
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .Open
End With

Set Me.Recordset = rst
Me.UniqueTable = "tblInventory"
rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
gCon.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found a satisfactory work-around. This is taken from [ASPAlliance](http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=989&pId=-1).

*For this we have to set the ResyncCommand Property of the Form in the design view to a SQL statement.*

*For Example: Resync Command:*

```
Select * From tblName where FieldName = ?
```

*If the Rowsource contains a stored procedure with multiple tables joined together then the Resync Command Property of the form should be set to an SQL statement that selects the same fields as the stored procedure and parameterize the primary key of the table that is designated as the Unique Table.*